# C++ filesystem lib not importing

Tags: c++, filesystems

I'm working on a small project with CMake and I'm trying to use the filesystem library to generate asset directories but when trying to use `namespace fs = std::filesystem` visual studio marks it with a red underline and it doesn't build correctly. I can't find any reason why this shouldn't work. The code I'm using is:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using a compiler that implements the C++17 standard, and you have configured the compiler accordingly?

Comment: Sam is right. If you're not using a C++ standard >= 17, Visual Studio will consider the `<filesystem>` header to be empty. add the standard as compile feature to the target via cmake `target_compile_features(MyTarget PRIVATE cxx_std_17)` (use `PUBLIC` if this is part of one of your public headers...

Comment: I'm probably being stupid asking this but what do I set for `MyTarget`? I'm not too experienced in CMake

Comment: Any reason you're using CMake, rather than just putting together a Visual Studio project?  Or are you using Visual Studio _Code_?

Comment: I'm using CMake because I want my project to be able to run on other operating systems and I heard that it is supposed to be easier to work with for packaging and distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was not using C++ Standard >= 17
By using `target_compile_features(MyTarget PRIVATE cxx_std_17)` in my CMakeLists.txt  suggested it fixed the issue of the `<filesystem>` header being empty